# Visual Studio Code Intellisense doesn't work with Opencv.JS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, opencv, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have reactjs + typescript web application which suppose to use opencv.js library for doing some vision tasks. However I can't make intellisense to work in my Visual Studio Code IDE for that library. I load library as following

```
var CV = require('../opencvLibs/build_js/bin/opencv_js.js');
class InnerApp extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    CV["onRuntimeInitialized"]= () => {
      let mat = new CV.Mat();
      console.log(mat.size());
      mat.delete();
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Provider rootStore = {new RootStore()}>
        <App/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <InnerApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

As you can see I am logging into console empty mat size just to check if library is working fine and I am getting width and height logged properly which indicates that library is loaded successfully.

I tried to add jsconfig.json file as I saw that as potential solution in official Visual Studio Code docs, however that didn't work.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6","dom"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "typings",
      "node_modules/@types"
  ]
  },
  "files":[
    "opencvLibs/build_js_wasm/bin/opencv.js"
  ]

}
```

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ],
    "include": [
        "opencvLibs/build_js/bin/opencv.js"
    ],
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "opencvLibs/build_js/bin/opencv.js"
        ]
    }

}
```

**webpack.dev.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HOST = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || '9000';

const config = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.tsx',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s?)css$/,
        use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.otf$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'dist/fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        //test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          //loader: 'url?limit=100000&name=[name].[ext]',
          options: {
            limit: 8192
          }
        }]
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    host: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    compress: true,
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    overlay: true,
    open: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options:{  
        scripts: [
        "../opencvLibs/build_js_wasm/bin/opencv.js"
      ]}
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      title: 'React Mobx Starter',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Expected result would be that intellisense works when I type "CV."

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Type definition for OpenCV.js is not available at the moment. You can try with custom typings mentioned [here](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/issues/511#issuecomment-307150090) or [here](https://github.com/johncant/DefinitelyTyped/blob/opencv/opencv/opencv-tests.d.ts). Track request for official typings [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15306)

Comment: Good to know, will track official typings. Cheers!